# Maximum tab width

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there possibility to set maximum (not larger than...) or fixed tab width?

Some of my files have long names, and by that reason, the tabs are visually inconsistent and inconvenient. Example:

[image]

I like how tabs are displayed in Chrome. Most of the time, they are fixed width:

[image]

There are some settings in `<ThemeName>.sublime-theme`, here they are:

```
{
    "class": "tabset_control",
    "tab_width": 180,
    "tab_min_width": 45
}
```

But adding `"tab_max_width"` doesn't make any effect.

Comment: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/194

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it's apparently part of theming, but since that was too complex for me (and tab_max_width doesn't do anything), i found editing user settings to include: `"enable_tab_scrolling" : false` did essentially something good enough to get by.